# How to get Parent class variable value in child class construct method

Tags: php, oop, parent-child

I have two files:

ParentClass.php

```
<?php

class ParentClass {

    public $variable1;
    public $variable2 = "Value of variable 2";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->variable1 = "Value of variable 1";
    }
}

$obj = new ParentClass;

?>
```

And ChildClass.php

```
<?php

include "ParentClass.php";

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    public function __construct()
    {
            echo $this->variable1;
            echo $this->variable2;
    }
}

$obj = new ChildClass;

?>
```

When I run the ChildClass file in browser, it gives me the the value of only variable 2. It does not show the value of variable1. I need to print both variable1 and variable2 values. Please Help.

Comment: You need to call the parent constructor from the ChildClass::__construct() method: `parent::__construct();`

Comment: Yes, the parent constructor is not call when you instantiate the child, you must call it in the child constructor.

Comment: I have already initiated ParentClass object so the constructor showed be executed automatically without calling it again in child class

Comment: When you did `$obj = new ChildClass;` it overwrote the `$obj` from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call parent::__construct() in your child contruct

the working code should be:

ParentClass.php

```php
<?php

class ParentClass {

    public $variable1;
    public $variable2 = "Value of variable 2";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->variable1 = "Value of variable 1";
    }
}

$obj = new ParentClass;

?>
```

And ChildClass.php

```php
<?php

include "ParentClass.php";

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct(); // like this
            echo $this->variable1;
            echo $this->variable2;
    }
}

$obj = new ChildClass;

?>
```

TRY this and see if it works :)

Comment: No I want to assign value to variable inside the constructor, not outside.

Comment: @AjmalRazeel you need to call ChildClass::__construct() method: parent::__construct();